# exessive object memory usage when not explicitly unsetting

Tags: php, garbage-collection

A colleague of mine wrote a script that was exhausting the available memory. I narrowed it down to the following basic test case:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 20; $i ++ ) {
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br />';
    $Survey = new Survey( 14 );
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br /><br />';
}
exit('done');
```

This breaks on the third iteration:

```
3116696
49123440

49123440
95518368

95518368
[E_ERROR] Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)
```

I managed to fix this, by simply adding an `unset()` call in the loop:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 20; $i ++ ) {
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br />';
    $Survey = new Survey( 14 );
    unset( $Survey );
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br /><br />';
}
exit('done');
```

Now the script goes through its 20 iterations nice and smooth, with a relatively constant memory usage:

```
3116816
49123488

49123488
50691656

50691656
51088912

51088912
51079064

51079064
50535368

50535368
50809296

50809296
51033392

51033392
51157208

51157208
50543856

50543856
50892760

50892760
51045160

51045160
51132688

51132688
50535968

50535968
50968632

50968632
51058080

51058080
51143304

51143304
50562136

50562136
51067432

51067432
51067768

51067768
51170824

51170824
50551712

done
```

This confuses me! Isn't the garbage collector supposed to clean up the object, as it's variable has been overwritten? I'm running PHP 5.3, so circular references can't be the cause of this problem.

Comment: @Rjik: are you sure there is any references to those objects somewhere else? no caching, no identity pattern?

Comment: may be silly... but what if you `unset` before creating new `$Survey`?

Comment: @RageZ: yep, I think I'm sure. There are references ín the object though..

Comment: The heuristics for running the GC (with cyclic reference detector) are pretty poor in PHP. As far as I know, the trigger for the GC is to have 10000 allocations in total, no matter the memory usage. In addition, the trigger counter does not seem to be adjustable. One would think it would make sense to run the GC if the memory limit were about to hit but I don't believe that this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Circular references can still be a problem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php#features.gc.cleanup-problems) in 5.3:

> **Cleanup Problems**
>
> Although there is no longer a symbol in any scope pointing to this
>   structure, it cannot be cleaned up because the array element "1" still
>   points to this same array. Because there is no external symbol
>   pointing to it, there is no way for a user to clean up this structure;
>   thus you get a memory leak. Fortunately, PHP will clean up this data
>   structure at the end of the request, but before then, this is taking
>   up valuable space in memory. This situation happens often if you're
>   implementing parsing algorithms or other things where you have a child
>   point back at a "parent" element. The same situation can also happen
>   with objects of course, where it actually is more likely to occur, as
>   objects are always implicitly used by reference.

There is probably also some memory-hogging resource inside `Survey` that takes up all of this memory; the observed behavior should be a combination of a ref cycle and such a resource.

What's in `Survey` exactly?

Comment: +1 for "memory-hogging", we're talking 40-45 MiB per object here. Is that really neccessary?

Comment: `Survey` represents a _really_ big questionnaire, with 4000+ questions (represented by child objects contained in the `Survey` object, that in turn contain an object for the answer). Reading up on the link, I guess my problem is probably caused by circular references; the `Question` objects have a reference back to the `Survey` in them. In any case, I'll have a look at trimming down the memory usage. Any other solutions/best practices for this (other than using `unset()` all the time)?

Comment: @Rijk: Just one: don't engineer your classes such that one instance can take up so much memory (use lazy or on-explicit-demand loading of data instead). That won't help you here, but `unset($survey)` is one hell of a cost-effective solution to this problem anyway.

Comment: @Rijk do you need all 4000 of those questions in one request? You could try to use some paging, if applicable.

Comment: We designed it with smaller surveys in mind (they usually aren't this big) -- in those cases this helps because you don't have to do a query for each single question. We might want to swap that for on-demand/lazy loading for large surveys (would that be better?).

What I still don't understand, though, is how come upgrading to PHP 5.3 did fix similar memory issues we were experiencing with smaller surveys, but not for this one.. Does the memory run out 'too fast' for the garbage collector to keep up?

Comment: I've found the answer! Posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the combination of circular references and the objects taking up 1/3rd of the available memory each. Changing the code to this:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 20; $i ++ ) {
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br />';
    gc_collect_cycles();
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br />';
    $Survey = new Survey( 14 );
    echo memory_get_usage(). '<br /><br />';
}
exit('done');
```

showed me:

```
3116456
3116680
49123288

49123288
49123288
95518160

95518160
50452344
96236360

96236360
50365776
96261312

96261312
50477296
96348608

96348608
50453072
96349752

96349752
50478440
96364872

96364872
50468192
96365240

96365240
50478808
96370760

96370760
50473712
96366072

96366072
50474120
96371448

96371448
50479088
96375352

96375352
50478024
96376672

96376672
50480408
96374984

96374984
50476336
96373032

96373032
50478456
96372216

96372216
50475520
96371288

96371288
50477528
96378824

96378824
50483056
96383992

96383992
50482696
96376592

96376592
50475656
96378072

done
```

You can clearly see that firing up the garbage collector manually frees up the memory taken up by the 'orphaned' object. I think the problem was there just was not enough time for the garbage collector to kick in, as the objects were so big.

The easiest solution for now is adding the `unset()` call - for the long term though I will be investigating ways to make the `Survey` object more memory-efficient.

Thanks to Jon and CodeCaster for pointing me in the right direction!